# Multi Language React App with Dynamic Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, web

I need a solution in which the user can add the data in selected language e.g(English, French, German), and save that data in all three languages in the Database so the user view that data according to the selected language.

I have tried with `React-Intl` and `I18n` but still not find the appropriate solution.

```
 [
     {
         "id": 1,
         "name_ar": "كرستوفر نولان",
         "name_en": "Christopher Nolan",
         "name_fr": "Christopher Nolan"
     },
     {
         "id": 2,
         "name_ar": "ميشيل جوندري",
         "name_en": "Michael Gondry",
         "name_fr": "Michael Gondry"
    }, 
]
```

I want to save the data like this just need one input and convert them according to the languages.

let me know if I am in the right direction.

Comment: You should at least put the code you tried here.

Comment: I18n libraries such as the ones you've linked are for a different use case (translating static messages etc.). This is just a matter of designing your data format, frontend and backend in a way that allows saving data in multiple languages. What are you using for the backend?

Comment: Yes I am using Nodejs at the backend.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not possible.  I18n libraries, including the official Intl or Intl.Locale is also not doing to help you.  The best case for you is that you ask that user to enter their name in every possible language, which nobody is ever going to do.

But even if you could "somehow" manage to do that, you still can't just randomly display that name in i.e. arabic to other users.  If another user doesn't have that charset loaded or "Arab" script loaded in their browser, it won't show that name.

Next thing you're going to ask a user to enter their Chinese traditional name and you will have no idea how to iterate over that or how to identify those unicode chars or even what the charset is.

There's a lot more to localization than just storing a bunch of names in the DB.  And you won't be able to do what you want to do using just DB storage.

Look into existing solutions like lingohub if you want to do things like this, however they aren't going to help you with names and surnames, but at least in combination with those you can find a way to show the "Arab" or "Hans" to other users.